# Remmina connections fail after fresh install of 20.04

Tags: remmina

I have switched from Mint 19.3 to Ubuntu 20.04, and among a few bugs I am encountering- the one that is really grinding things to a halt is the remmina connections failing. I have used the PPA and snap install, I moved my old connections over from /.local/share/remmina and the appear fine, however no matter the settings I use (RDP sec, TLS, etc) they will not connect. I have also flushed the knownhosts, and the saved connections and attempted to recreate a few, but still fail. They worked fine in Mint- although remmina and freerdp were an older version, but this is my first dive back into Ubuntu in a number of years. The RDP server are a mix of Win Server 2008/2012/2016/2019 and I have roughly 300 of them that all fail. If left at the default settings it prompts for a un/pw which always fails. If any other security setting is tried, it just fails without a reason. I have not been able to come up with much in the way of tips online.